Avro Schema Parsing Error while parsing in order
I have two schemas where both the schemas have dependency. When I am parsing the schemas in order, the parse function in avro.schema couldn't identify the dependencies. How to resolve this issue?
schema_1.avsc
[
  {
    "namespace": "com.sc.db.lib.sd.common",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "CorrelationId",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Type",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "namespace": "com.sc.db.lib.sd.common",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "NamedResourceReference",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.sc.db.lib.tracking",
    "name": "ErrorMessageDetails",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "errorMessage",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "errorDetails",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  }
]

schema_2.avsc
[
  {
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.sc.db.lib.sourcedata",
    "name": "BusinessAsset",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "id",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "string"
        ],
        "default": null
      },
      {
        "name": "organization",
        "type": [
          "null",
          "com.sc.db.lib.sd.common.NamedResourceReference"
        ],
        "default": null
      }
    ]
  }
]

Below is the parsing code that i am parsing using avro.schema
from avro.schema import parse


# Path to your Avro schemas
schema_dir = '/home/jupyter/kafka/schemas'

schema_files = [
    'schema_1.avsc',
    'schema_2.avsc',

]

Parse each Avro schema in the correct order
known_schemas = {}
for schema_file in schema_files:
    schema_path = f'{schema_dir}/{schema_file}'
    print("schema_path--->", schema_path)
    with open(schema_path, 'r') as f:
        schema_str = f.read()
        json_data = json.loads(schema_str)
        for schema_data in json_data:
            print('known_schemas:',known_schemas)
            schema = parse(json.dumps(schema_data), known_schemas)
            
            known_schemas[schema.fullname] = schema

Error:
SchemaParseException: Type property "['null', 'com.sc.dv.lib.sd.common.NamedResourceReference']" not a valid Avro schema: Union item must be a valid Avro schema: Could not make an Avro Schema object from com.sc.dv.lib.sd.common.NamedResourceReference

